# Не работает отправка E-mail на php

Tags: php

Не работает оправка E-mail'а на php. Хостинг беру тут от hostinger. Вот код:

```
else if ($_POST['register_f']) {

email_valid();
password_valid();
//captcha_valid();

if ( mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$_POST[email]'")) )
    message('Цей E-mail зайнятий');


 $code = random_str(5);

 $_SESSION['confirm'] = array(
    'type' => 'register',
    'email' => $_POST['email'],
    'password' => $_POST['password'],
    'code' => $code,
    );

mail($_POST['email'], 'Реєстрація', "Код підтвердження реєстрації: <b>$code</b>");


go('confirm');
```

}

Comment: Вообще не работает? Или скажем, в спам падает?

Comment: Вообще не работает

Comment: `mail` что возвращает? true?

Comment: А как проверить что он возращает?

Comment: Приехали. Ну, допустим `var_dump(mail(...));die();`

Comment: Когда пишу `var_dump(mail(...));die();` ругается javascript вот такой ошибкой

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token b in JSON at position 0
    at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (script.js:20)
    at i (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)`

Comment: F12 - Network, там смотри ответ сервера

Comment: <b>$code</b> - вот это не будет работать как хтмл,заголовки отправить нужно Content-Type: text/html;

Comment: А что, так трудно зайти в документацию и взять готовый код из примеров? Не понимаю я людей которые хотят писать авось как лишь бы работало - http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php